# How to save complete data of JTextArea in to single cell of csv file

Tags: java, swing, csv, jtextarea

Iam saving JTextArea data in to csv file, but application is not saving the entire data in single cell.

for example:
In JTextArea i added data as below

```
apple
mango
banana
guava
```

In .csv file it is saving in four rows instead of single row.

below is my code how iam saving the data.

```
String address ;
address = textArea.getText();
writer.append(address);
writer.append(',');
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix the issue?

Thanks

Comment: If I remember the CSV format correctly, you can only include the newlines if you place the whole value for that CSV cell inside ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not replace the newline characters of the `JTextArea` with the commas to give you a single CSV row:

```
writer.append(address.replace("\n", ","));
```

Output:

```
apple,mango,banana,guava
```

Comment: if you append "," it will insert in next cell

Comment: to be frank the way you suggested its not work, getting same output as previous

Comment: The output given above is the actually output that the replace will give. Unless there is something else in your code causing this?

Comment: iam printing address before replace and after replace, "," is not getting replaced with new line character

Comment: 1+ Oh my madness, iam not assigning back to address after replacing. But if i use , for replacing it will place in next cell of the row. Instead i have to use some other character, i used "-" then it worked. Thanks Reimeus , even it is partial answer but i managed to work with ur idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
writer.append(address.replace("\n", "-"));

Use character other than ",". If not, data will be placed in consecutive cell of the same row
```